# Multivariate Time series forecasting (Sales prediction) using ML techniques

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I am looking for pointers to get started on a use case where I want to predict the Sales for t+1, t+2, t+3 using multiple features which may impact the Sales. I do not have data for these features for future months. I have historical data for last 24 months. Most of the blog I have read talks about univariate time series forecasting but in real world scenarios, there can be multiple features which may impact the target variable.
So, it's a typical case of multivariate time series forecasting. Also, whether it will be good to explore statistical model or ML techniques?